# How to iterate through an arraylist of an arraylist of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, iteration

I'm creating a program that allows users to interact with a file thats input.  One of the options is to display the file.  Below, I store the file into an arraylist first by creating arraylists consisting of lines, and then an inner arraylist separated of strings, separated by spaces.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileName);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] words = {};
        words = line.split(" ");
        ArrayList<String> lineArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            lineArray.add(words[i]);
        }
        fileByLine.add(lineArray);
    }
    sc.close();
```

I'm trying to print the contents of the arraylist, called fileByLine, as they appear in the file, but I'm not sure how to. Any suggestion?

```
case '1':
for(int i = 0; i < fileByLine.size(); i++){
for(int j = 0; j < fileByLine.[i].size(); j++){
System.out.print(fileByLine[i][j]);
  } System.out.println("");
} break;
```

Comment: What does the current output look like?

Comment: @Ally Please update the formatting of your second code sample to make it more legible. And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using bracket notation which is for arrays, you need to use get() for arraylists

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileByLine.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < fileByLine.get(i).size(); j++){
        System.out.print(fileByLine.get(i).get(j));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I was trying to do but couldn't quite get right... the code executes perfectly now :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your container consist of `String type` you can just print it as follow:

```
System.out.println(fileByLine);
```

No need to loop through your collection. For example, let's say you have following list:

```
List<String> oneList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1 2 3 4 5 6 7".split(" ")));
```

and you want to add it into another list:

```
List<List<String>> anotherList = new ArrayList<>();
anotherList.add(oneList);
```

After adding you would like to print it and here is how it looks:

```
System.out.println(anotherList);
```

> Output: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

It prints because of `String type` if you keep any other `custom type` in your container and try to print it that will not work until you `override toString()` method.

If you need to iterate over two nested lists you can use this approach too:

```
Iterator<List<String>> outerIterator = anotherList.listIterator();

while (outerIterator.hasNext()) {
    Iterator<String> innerIterator = outerIterator.next().listIterator();

    while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {
        String item = innerIterator.next();
        System.out.print(item + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this as well...

```
     for (List list : fileByLine) {
        for (Object line : list) {
            System.out.print(line);
        }
        System.out.println("");
     }
```